# Moving wordpress from local to server with git (sourcetree)

Tags: database, wordpress, local, live

I am new to working with GIT, I found out how to commit and push everything, so that's working. I installed my wordpress blog locally and worked on the theme and plugins for a while and now I want it to be live.

So what I did now;
- I exported my database from MAMP's PHPmyadmin
- I imported my database with Sequel Pro
- I pushed my blog live with SourceTree

And now it says; Error establishing a database connection.
Of course I have already changed the wp-config file but I guess I'm doing something wrong..

I'm using cloudvps so I entered 'localhost' as my host, I know I have the right password and username because I was able to login using Sequel Pro. The database name is obviously the name of the database I imported, it says 'vanillalooks' in Sequel Pro, because I named it so, and that's what I have entered in the wp-config file.

Now why does it have problems connecting to the database? Have I missed any steps?

Comment: Could you provide some more information on where your database is hosted and what the specs of that is.

Comment: At cloudvps.com. TBH I can't find the specs right now but I know it is possible to run wordpress blogs on it, because they do state that on the website. Do you need to know more than that? If so I can make a call.

Answer (score 0):

You explained that `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');` is what you are using for your database connection in the config file, if this is in fact the case that is not what you want to use here. This only works when your server and database server are in reality on the same computer. This does not seem to be the case for you. You will instead have to write something as followed: `define('DB_HOST', 'host_name_atcloudvps.com');` That will allow wordpress to establish a connection to the correct server.

Comment: I have always learned you should be using “localhost” as you would be connecting to the database server which is on the same server that your website is hosted on. I have tried (my hostname is vanillalooks.nl) vanillalooks.nl_atcloudvps.com and vanillalooks_atcloudvps.com and both didn't work. I tried asking cloudvps if they know what the host should be, I'm hoping for a quick response. Thank you for your answer though!